# Fourier transform of creation and annihilation operators in Kitaev Chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, fourier-transform

I encounter a problem when I use Fourier transformation to transform the real space Kitaev Chain to momentum space. Suppose the real space Kitaev Chain can be written as follow:
\begin{equation}
 H_{KM} = -\sum^{N-1}_{i} (t c^{\dagger}_{i} c_{i+1} + tc^{\dagger}_{i+1} c_{i} + \Delta c^{\dagger}_{i} c^{\dagger}_{i+1} + \Delta^{*}c_{i+1}c_{i}) - \mu \sum^{N}_{i}c^{\dagger}_{i} c_{i}
\end{equation}
And the expected result should be like this ([Hamiltonian for the Periodic Kitaev Model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114506/hamiltonian-for-the-periodic-kitaev-model)) :
\begin{equation}
H_{k} =  -\sum_{k}( 2t \cos(k) +  \mu) c^{\dagger}_{k} c_{k} + \Delta e^{-ik}c^{\dagger}_{k} c^{\dagger}_{-k} + \Delta^{*} e^{ik} c_{k}c_{-k}) 
\end{equation}
However, when I use the Fourier transform $ c_{j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k} e^{-ikx_{j}} c_{k}$ to manipulate the midterm two terms $c^{\dagger}_{i} c^{\dagger}_{i+1}$ and $c_{i}c_{i+1}$, I got a trouble there since I cannot get the correct phase $e^{\pm ik}$. My calculation steps are as follow:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{i} c^{\dagger}_{i} c^{\dagger}_{i+1} &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{kqi} c^{\dagger}_{k} c^{\dagger}_{q}  e^{ix_{i}k} e^{iqx_{i+1}} \\
&=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{kqi} c^{\dagger}_{k} c^{\dagger}_{q}  e^{ix_{i}k} e^{iqx_{I}} e^{iq} ~~~~ \text{($x_{i+1} = x_{i} + 1$)}  \\
&= \sum_{kq} c^{\dagger}_{k} c^{\dagger}_{q}e^{iq}  \big(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i} e^{ix_{i}(k+q)} \big) \\ 
&= \sum_{kq} c^{\dagger}_{k}c^{\dagger}_{q} e^{iq}\delta_{k,-q}\\
&= \sum_{k} c^{\dagger}_{k}c^{\dagger}_{-k} e^{-ik}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Similarly for $c_{i+1}c_{i}$ term
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{i} c_{i+1} c_{i} &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{kqi} c_{k} c_{q}  e^{-ix_{i+1}k} e^{-iqx_{i}} \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{kqi} c_{k} c_{q} e^{-ik} e^{-ikx_{i}} e^{-iqx_{i}} ~~~~ \text{($e^{-ikx_{i+1}} =e^{-ik(x_{i} +1)} $)} \\
&=\sum_{kq} c_{k} c_{q} e^{-ik} \big( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i} e^{-i(k+q)x_{i}}\big) \\ 
&= \sum_{kq} c_{k}c_{-k} e^{-ik} \delta_{k,-q} \\ 
&= \sum_{k} c_{k}c_{-k} e^{-ik} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Therefore, could anyone help me to point out the mistakes that I made in my calculation? Thank you.

Comment: For the Fourier Transform of $c^{\dagger}$, I directly take the conjugation of the Fourier transform of $c$. Therefore, I use $c^{\dagger}_{i} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k} e^{ikx_{i}} c^{\dagger}_{k}$ as the Fourier transform of $c^{\dagger}_{i}$

Comment: Are you sure that $H_k$ is correct? It doesn't look hermitian.

Comment: I am not sure whether the $H_{k}$ is correct. I saw some examples in BCS theory, the $H_{k}$ should contain $c_{-k}c_{k}$ instead of $c_{k}c_{-k}$. This is also a problem that confused me a lot.  Besides, may I ask how to check Hermitian of such Hamiltonian?

Comment: For it to be hermitian - unless I am missing sth. - the last term should have $c_{-k}c_k$. And then your result is correct (substitute $k$ with $-k$).

Comment: This is a comment but: you don't need to work out the second $\propto \Delta$ term like this. The two pairing terms are hermitian conjugates in real space and will be in momentum space - just do the FT of one of them and then write the h.c. of it for the second.

Comment: You are right, jacob1729. I forgot they are Hermitian conjugate. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to be hermitian, the Hamiltonian should read
\begin{equation}
H_{k} =  -\sum_{k}( 2t \cos(k) +  \mu) c^{\dagger}_{k} c_{k} + \Delta e^{-ik}c^{\dagger}_{k} c^{\dagger}_{-k} + \Delta^{*} e^{ik} c_{-k}c_{k}) \ ,
\end{equation}
or something the like.

This is what your derivations gives:
Substitute $k\to-k$ and use $\sum_k=\sum_{-k}$, and you get
$$
\sum k c_kc_{-k} = \sum_q c_{-k} c_{k} e^{ik}\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now understand how to how to check the hermitian.